# Attribute routing for POST in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, attributerouting, asp.net-core-routing

The following give me `args=null` when I `POST` with a body `{"args": 222}`. How can I get the member of the body into my variable `args` (or the entire body into a variable `body`)

```
[HttpPost("{className}/{methodName}")]
public ActionResult<string> Post(string className, string methodName, string args){}
```

Comment: You can try put [FromBody] attribute before your args parameter

Comment: didnt work. I tried that.

Comment: what is the type of HttpPost ?

Comment: POST, with body as {
 "args": 222
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON

```
{"args": 222}
```

implies that `args` is a number.

Create a model to hold the expected data

```
public class Data {
    public int args { get; set; }
}
```

Update the action to explicitly expect the data from the request body

```
[HttpPost("{className}/{methodName}")]
public ActionResult<string> Post(string className, string methodName, [FromBody] Data body) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        int args = body.args
        //...
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Attribute Routing, you have to enable Attribute routing at the WebAPIConfig. Also have a [Route()] for every action PUT, GET, POST etc.

What I see you are doing is conventional routing.

For more info on attribute routing, i suggest you go through this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2